# Dropdown not selected value in PHP

Tags: php, html, dropdown

My PHP code:

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/baglanti.php');

  $settings= $db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM mestan_settings");
  $settings-> execute(array());
  $settingswrite = $settings->fetchALL();
  foreach($settingswrite as $row_settings);

  ?>
```

This my form code:

```
<select name="yorum" class="form-control" id="yorum" >
      <option value="1" <?php if ($row_settings['yorum'] ==1) echo ' selected="selected"'?>>Comments Open</option>
      <option value="0" <?php if ($row_settings['yorum'] == 0) echo ' selected="selected"'?>>Comments Close</option>
</select>
```

My update form has not selected comments to open or close. MySQL value 0 or 1.

Comment: try removing the space before `selected` `echo 'selected="selected"'`

Comment: Where do you define `$row_settings`?

Comment: Vote to close as a typo

Answer (score 0):

The selected attribute is a solitary attribute, you don't need to write `selected="selected"`. Only `selected` is enough.

Try this :

```
<option value="1" <?= $row_settings['yorum'] ? "selected" : "" ?>>Comments Open</option>    
<option value="0" <?= $row_settings['yorum'] ? "" : "selected" ?>>Comments Close</option>
```

Comment: The way the OP has it is fine. The extra space before selected is the issue

Comment: You talk about the whitespace between "echo" and "selected=" ? But HTML don't care about it, I just test with 10 whitespace and it work too.